# What dependencies are required for DataNucleus 3.0.0-release?

Tags: java, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I'm trying to use datanucleus as JPA provider for GAE. This is my `pom.xml` (part of it):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-release</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-release</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-release</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Class finding exception is thrown in runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/jpa/exceptions/NoPersistenceXmlException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator.getServices(ProviderLocator.java:319)
at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:108)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:91)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
...
```

Where this `org.datanucleus.jpa.exceptions.NoPersistenceXmlException` class is located? What JAR did I miss?

Comment: You mean where is it referenced from ? From a DataNucleus 1.x jar which you haven't removed from the CLASSPATH

Comment: Actually, looking at your classpath you have "com.google.appengine.orm" v1.0.8 which Googles docs state very clearly is to be used with DataNucleus 1.x ... cos that is all it supports. GAE/J SVN has code that will work with DataNucleus 3.x

Answer (score 1):

[Official Link For Maven](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/maven.html)

would provide the required info. If not, do mention here as @DataNucleus can update the website in such an event.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

[Source](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-jpa/2.1.8)

Also, note that it has 

geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec

datanucleus-core

geronimo-validation_1.0_spec

Comment: No you don't. Thats DataNucleus 2.x

Comment: Okay, I might be wrong. But pls do provide the correct solution to person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works (it's datanucleus 1.x, which is the highest version that works with GAE):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```